# Qt QVector allocation via resize() results in bad_alloc where reserve() seems to work

Tags: c++, qt, allocation, qvector

So I want to allocate 1GB of data in QVector. So far I use something like this:

```
void foo (float* data, size_t size)
{
    QVector<float> resultVec;
    resultVec.resize(size);

    //I do some stuff on the vector

    size_t paddingLength = nextPow2(size); //calculates the next highest power 2 two

    //the paddingLength in this case is at the moment: 268.435.456
    // this results in bad_alloc
    resultVec.resize(paddingLength); 

}
```

So in the case of floats I want to reserve 1Gb worth of space. This should not be a problem at all. I still have like 11GB on RAM left. I tried it at another point in the program and it works perfectly fine, even with sizes in the order of 4GB.

My first guess was I just don't have enough continuous space left, but when I try to do the same by reserving the space before resizing it, it suddenly works.

```
void foo (float* data, size_t size)
{
    QVector<float> resultVec;
    resultVec.resize(size);

    //I do some stuff on the vector

    size_t paddingLength = nextPow2(size); //calculates the next highest power 2 two

    //the paddingLength in this case is at the moment: 268.435.456
    //this works tho
    resultVec.reserve(paddingLength);
    resultVec.resize(paddingLength); 

}

template<typename T>
T nextPow2 (const T val)
{
    T result = val;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT; i *= 2)
    {
        result |= result >> i;
    }
    return result + 1;
}
```

FYI: I did check the return value of next2Pow and I am sure that it is smaller than the limit of an int. As shown in the comments my value is a bit over 268 million elements, where an int has a maximum of over 2 billion, so I should be safe there. I included my next2pow implementation above.

Am i doing something wrong, or is this behaviour to be expected?

Comment: According to the docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html), `QVector` is a templated class.  So how did your code compile with this line: `QVector resultVec;`?

Comment: Aside from the question above, I'm curious if you observe the same result with `std::vector`, at the same points in the program. As far as I know `QVector` has no special resize / reserve interaction, but I've never attempted to use it with allocations that large. (Not to say it can't be used for them)

Comment: Also, the docs also state that the number of elements to resize / reserve in a QVector to be `int`.  Did you check for an `int` overflow for the return value of `nextPow2`?  Or that the total number of items in your `QVector` is greater than the max `int` value?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Indeed. I corrected the line. I did not copy my code, but wrote it by hand. Edited my post for your second remark.

Comment: @JamesTurner I just tried it with std::vector<float> and I do not get a bad_alloc by using the resize method directly.

Comment: After quick glance to QT source code, I noticed that `reserve` tries to allocate exactly asked amount, when `resize` will try to allocate half again as much memory, if resizing exceeds capacity. Potentially it can lead to overflow, like @PaulMcKenzie suggested. I currently do not have means to check if it is indeed a problem in your case, so I would suggest to run debugger and watch how much memory vector tries to allocate.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot So I stepped through the source code too, I to be honest I cannot find, where resize is behaving different from reserve. They both call the same reallocData() function. They also both try to allocate exactly the amount of elements, that I request. But somehow reserve is working fine, while resize is failing.

Comment: @FreddyKay The difference, at least with `std::vector`, is that `resize()` has to construct new objects, not just allocate memory.  For example, if your vector is empty, and you just do a `reserve(10)` item, and then tried to do a `vector::at(0)`, you get an `out_of_range` exception since the items were not really constructed.  If QVector has the same behavior, then that's the difference between reserve and resize with QVector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware of that. But it misses the point. In both cases, the memory for the elements must be allocated first. This is where I get an exception. I stepped through the code and it fails to allocate memory in the case of resize() and is successful in the case of reserve(). This seems weird to me. I take it, this behaviour is not reproduceable, therefore there must be a problem with my concrete implementation or worse, situation on the computer